# Pig: get data from hive table and add partition as column

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have a partitioned *Hive* table that i want to load in a *Pig* script and would like to add partition as column also.

How can I do that?

Table definition in Hive:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions
(
column1 string,
column2 string
)
PARTITIONED BY (datestamp string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION '/path';
```

Pig script:

```
%default INPUT_PATH '/path'

A = LOAD '$INPUT_PATH'
         USING PigStorage('|')
         AS (
         column1:chararray, 
         column2:chararray,
         datestamp:chararray  
         );
```

The `datestamp` column is not populated. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I didn't get the part which says **add partition as column also**. Once created, partition keys behave like regular columns. What exactly do you need?

And you are loading the data directly from a given HDFS location, not as a Hive table. If you intend to use Pig to load/store data from/into a Hive table you should use ***[HCatalog](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog)***.

**For example :**

```
A = LOAD 'transactions' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```